# Jquery filtering with Ajax results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

new here and fairly new to programming too. Essentially, what i'm trying to do is create a select menu with 3 options in it, each option having a different value. I want to use this to filter Results searched and called in via Ajax. I have attached a "data" attribute that will look like "data-type:0" the 0 being echo'd in from a SQL table column.

So far this part works. The issue i'm having comes when I select, for example value "0". It'll hide and filter all 0's and 1's IF the first result is a "0", when it should be iterating over each of Objects that are getting called in (in the form of Divs) and not hiding ones that don't match, I also have a requirement to make the previously filtered results return if the selector value changes.

I've been experimenting with Jquery, as I can't find a plugin that does this that isn't super out of date, so below is my code. So far it just hides everything, my suspicion is, is that is just hiding everything if the first result matches (i.e. it'll hide all 0's and 1's if the first result is 0 and the selector is). I just can't figure out why it isn't iterating.

```
function EMCfilt() {

    var filteroption = $("#filtlist").val();
    document.getElementById("filtlist").value;

    if (filteroption == '1') {
        $(".imghalf").each(function() {
            return $(".imghalf").data("emcscbi") == '1';
        })
        $('.imghalf').css('display', 'none');
        $(".imghalf").each(function() {
            return $(".imghalf").data("emcscbi") == '0';
        })
        $('imghalf').css('display', 'inline-block');
    } else if (filteroption == '0') {
        $(".imghalf").each(function() {
            return $(".imghalf").data("emcscbi") == '0';
        })
        $('.imghalf').css('display', 'none');

        $(".imghalf").each(function() {
            return $(".imghalf").data("emcscbi") == '1';
        })
        $('.imghalf').css('display', 'inline-block');
    } else if (filteroption == '') {
        $('.imghalf').css('display', 'inline-block ');
    }

}
```

If you've any advice/solution  i'd appreciate it immensely. .Imghalf is part of the html of the results, which come in the form of cards. Each card's parent div is .imghalf, so this contains the data-emcscbi:x

Thanks.

edit:

Here is the html that is generated for each card, These get called into a  via ajax :

```
 .'<div class=imghalf id=imghalf data-emcscbi='. 
 $result['NotSingleFind?']. '>'

 .'<img  class=coinimg .$result['CoinID']. 'obv.jpg </img>'  ' if 
 file_exists(filename)) { echo $filename } else { echo 
 $emptyfile}; ' */
 .'<div class=listhalf>'
 .'<ul id=coincard>'
 .'<img  class=coinimg src=images/' . $filename . ' 
 onError="imgError(this);"</img>'
 .'<li class=coincarditem>'.' EMC NUMBER: '. $result['objNum']. '</li>'
 .'<li class=coincarditem>'. 
 htmlentities(mb_convert_encoding($result['Title'], 'UTF-8', 'ASCII'), 
 ENT_SUBSTITUTE, "UTF-8"). '</li>'
 .'<li class=coincarditem>'. 
 htmlentities(mb_convert_encoding($result['RulerName'], 'UTF-8', 
'ASCII'), 
ENT_SUBSTITUTE, "UTF-8"). '</li>'
.'<li class=coincarditem>'. $result['StateName']. '</li>'
.'<li class=coincarditemhidden id=coincarditemhidden>'.  
$result['NotSingleFind?']. '</li>'
.'<li class=coincarditem>'.'<a id=cardref href="#Focus_Result?
link='.$result['CoinID'].'" onclick="setTimeout(printurl, delay)">Full 
Record</a>'.'</li>'
.'</ul>'
.'</div>'
.'</div>';
```

This would be the final output after performing a search:

```
<div class="imghalf" id="imghalf" data-emcscbi="1"><div 
class="listhalf"><ul id="coincard"><img class="coinimg" 
src="images/1001.0563obv.jpg" onerror="imgError(this);" <="" img=""><li 
class="coincarditem"> EMC NUMBER: 1001.0563</li><li 
class="coincarditem">Danelaw (Edward imitations)</li><li 
class="coincarditem">anon. (Viking imitations of Edward)</li><li 
class="coincarditem">Danelaw (880-924)</li><li 
class="coincarditemhidden" id="coincarditemhidden">1</li><li 
class="coincarditem"><a id="cardref" href="#Focus_Result?
link=1001.0563" onclick="setTimeout(printurl, delay)">Full Record</a>
</li></ul></div></div>
```

So one of these snippets for each record in the database that is queried, limited at the moment to 50. I know that the "filteroption" variable is being set correctly to 1 or 0 or null when the value is changed. I used console.log(filteroption) to work that out, as you can see the "data-" part gets set correctly.

Comment: would be a lot easier to figure out if we could see the HTML as well.

Comment: You may want to read up on [How to write a Minimal Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Think around the problem, what is the minimal functionality you need to be able to reproduce the issue you are having.

Comment: I've added it to the initial post, thanks for the pointer

Comment: The Javascript can only operate on the final HTML output, so actually that would be far more useful in the context of the question than the PHP which generates it. It leaves some uncertainty about what the actual final HTML will look like due to the use of conditionals, variables and functions. You can get the final HTML by using the View Source feature in your browser after the page is loaded.

Comment: I built an answer mostly as a way of demonstrating a minimal functional example :), hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I built a minimal example to demonstrate this, my jQuery is super rusty so I did it in vanilla JS. To start I think your if/else block is a bit overcomplicated logically, if you are filtering on one set of conditions its usually better to grab everything edit it to your base state (invisible) then make only the matching sections become visible. To accomplish this i used a class `hidden` that could be added and removed easily.

Working with HTMLCollections in JavaScript you will make extensive use of the [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method which you can use to apply array-like iterable objects to Array functions (odd I know). I use ES6 Arrow functions here for the callbacks, you can sub those out for standard functions with no changes if you prefer (or need to support older browsers). You could also trade `let` and `const` out for `var`, but [block scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) is amazing :)

```js
// Get your select dropdown by id (eg: $('#filtlist');)
const select = document.getElementById('filtlist');

// Apply an event listener with callback to select element
// (eg: select.on('change', callbackfunction());)
select.addEventListener('change', e => {
  // get all matching elements to classname ( $('.imghalf'); )
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('imghalf');
  
  // if selected option is '' make everything visible and return
  if (e.target.value === '') { 
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, val => { val.classList.remove('hidden') });
    return; 
  }
  // grab and format selected option to a number
  const option = Number(e.target.value);
 
  //  Foreach is exactly what you would expect for each value in collection, do this function (maybe - $.each(elements, function); ) 
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, val => { val.classList.add('hidden'); });
  // filter by matching data option to select option, returns HTMLCollection
  let visible = Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, val => Number(val.dataset.emcscbi) === option);
  // Make matching elements visible
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(visible, val => { val.classList.remove('hidden') })
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none }
.imghalf { width: 100%; height: 30px; border: 1px solid black; }
.odd { background-color: gray; }
.even { background-color: white; }

#filtlist { margin: 30px auto; }
```

```html
<select id="filtlist">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<section class="example">
  <article class="imghalf odd" data-emcscbi="1"></article>
  <article class="imghalf even" data-emcscbi="2"></article>
  <article class="imghalf odd" data-emcscbi="1"></article>
  <article class="imghalf even" data-emcscbi="2"></article>
  <article class="imghalf odd" data-emcscbi="1"></article>
  <article class="imghalf even" data-emcscbi="2"></article>
  <article class="imghalf odd" data-emcscbi="1"></article>
  <article class="imghalf even" data-emcscbi="2"></article>
  <article class="imghalf odd" data-emcscbi="1"></article>
  <article class="imghalf even" data-emcscbi="2"></article>
</section>
```

### EDIT

OP asked about what the `e` in the callback for the event was. `select.addEventListener('change', e => {})`

In JS your callback function will take arguments based on what function it is being passed to, so in the case of an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) you are being passed an event object. Your callback function is expected to know what to do with that object. You can ignore it if you don't need it (`function() {} OR () => {}`) but it is always passed to your callback.

Commonly (especially in jQuery) you will see code with no `event` argument but with references to `this`

```
$(selector).on('change', function() { console.log(this.value) }
selector.addEventListener('change', function() { console.log(this.value) }
```

This works with standard functions and is a common shorthand for `event.target`, but ES6 arrow functions [lexically binds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) this to the parent's scope (sounds complicated, but it means that your arrow using `this` is pointing at the scope it is called in, instead of its own internal scope)

```
// Does not work as you would expect.
selector.addEventListener('change', () => { console.log(this.value) });
```

So when using arrow functions (or just in general as a good practice) you should remember that your callbacks for events will have event objects passed to them.

```
const eventHandler = event => { /* do the things */ };
const eventAlsoHandler = function(event) { /* do the things */ };
function eventAnotherHandler(event) { /* do the things */ }
element.addEventListener('change', eventHandler);
```

In answering your question i used `event.target` which is probably one of the most common, but there are a ton of useful things in that [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#Properties). Other really common things to see are `preventDefault`, `stopPropagation`. Different events will also add other properties (small example, [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) events add `event.key` for the string representation of the key that was pressed).

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it does exactly what I'm after. The one thing I'm not so sure on is :  select.addEventListener('change', e => { .   So this is picking up when the select is changed to run the script that does the rest of the function, but what is the "e" (I can't see this referenced in the ES6 Arrow functions. Is it a variable that takes the value of the select? (I don't think it is, because itsn't that what "select" is?  Sorry if this is dumb, I really need to improve my Javascript! Thanks for taking the time to provide what looks to be a great answer!

Comment: No worries, everyone starts somewhere :). I'll edit my answer to explain this in some detail.